Getting "Possible mixed-content issue" on Flask/Swagger with HTTPS through CloudFront
I'm trying to deploy my Flask app to EC2 and use the certificate generated by AWS Certificate Manager. I've made a few extra configurations but I still get this error when I navigate to the https URL.
Fetch error
Failed to fetch http://dev-api.mydomain.com/swagger.json

Fetch error
Possible mixed-content issue? The page was loaded over https:// but a http:// URL was specified. Check that you are not attempting to load mixed content.

I'm running my Flask project using Gunicorn (port 8000) and I have Nginx set up to listen on port 80 and redirect to 8000. Then, I created a distribution on AWS CloudFront with HTTPS to HTTP redirect (initially I was trying with a Load Balancer for my EC2 instance, but it requires instances in two availability zones, and that's overkill for what I need).
Here's how I've set this up:
start.sh
source /home/ec2-user/backend/venv/bin/activate
exec gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 app:app

/etc/nginx/sites-available/flask-app.conf (with symlink to ../sites-enabled)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dev-api.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;  # Add this line
        proxy_set_header CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto $http_cloudfront_forwarded_proto;
    }
}

What am I missing here?
